# Error using Apple frameworks in my CocoaPod podspec?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, watchkit, podspec

I have a cross platform library that I'm trying to push to CocoaPod, but the it is failing on the podspec validation. The error I get is:

- ERROR | xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  MyPod/Sources/CLKComplicationServer.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'ClockKit'

I tried adding the frameworks to my podspec, but it is still not accepting. Here is what my podspec looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    ...
    s.ios.deployment_target = "8.4"
    s.watchos.deployment_target = "2.0"
    s.tvos.deployment_target = "9.0"

    s.requires_arc = true

    s.ios.framework = 'AVFoundation'
    s.watchos.framework = 'ClockKit'

    s.source_files = "Sources/**/*.{h,swift}"
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm having the same issue with `AVFoundation`. I tried adding both to my header file, but `ClockKit` is not recognized.

Comment: Same issue for me with 'AppKit', see here: https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandySwift/commit/0a6a8ddb77a0ba23f8158f01204fc6bf9b9eed02